# Kubernetes - easy way to declaratively include a config file?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, containers

Trying to copy over a nginx conf file for my pod to use (lives at `<project>/nginx.conf`). With Docker compose I'd simply do the following...

```
image: "nginx:alpine"
ports:
- "80:80"
volumes:
- ./nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
```

Best practice? Unsure as this is new-ish to me. It did seemingly work well. I'd like to accomplish the same with a kubernetes deployment but am not finding a straightforward way to do this *declaratively*. I came across a bit on [ConfigMap](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-configmap/), but was a little resistant when immediately met with the following...

> Use the kubectl create configmap command to create configmaps from
>   directories, files, or literal values

I don't want a lot of remember-these-commands-down-the-roads' scattered in text files and much prefer the file approach as shown with compose. Is this achievable? My spec so far looks as such...

```
spec:
  containers:
  - name: nginx
    image: nginx:alpine
    ports:
    - containerPort: 80
      name: http
```

Help me the get config in here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ConfigMaps are absolutely the way to go. You can create a configmap using a spec like the following:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: nginx
  namespace: default
data:
  nginx.conf: |-
     user www;
     worker_processes 5; 
     ...
     # all nginx.conf file contents goes here
```

Once you applied your configmap using kubectl, you can mount it in your container, by specifying the following in the PodSpec:

```
containers:
- name: ...
  ...
  volumeMounts:
  - name: nginx-volume
    mountPath: <path where you want to put nginx.conf>
volumes:
- name: nginx-volume
  configMap:
    name: nginx
```

Please note that the directory you will choose as a mount point for your nginx.conf file will contain only that file (hiding all other files already present in that directory), exactly as it happens when mounting a device on a non empty directory in linux.

A lot more details on configmaps here: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-configmap/

Comment: Interesting, so it looks like you can actually make a `ConfigMap` through config opposed to the commands. Hm, this seems promising. Quickly, how about where I specify my local `./nginx.conf` file? I see you truncated `...` in the `data` directive, so is there somewhere I can specify the local file to be copied? Thanks

Comment: The ... Is just a placeholder to keep answer short. You can put all your config file in the yaml where you define the ConfigMap

Comment: What directive is it though? e.g. `user `, `worker_processes`... How do I specify a local file? I have to actually put the contents there? I can't point to a file? grr

Comment: Disregard what I said about directives, I see now you just have a raw nginx config in there. I can see that getting really gnarly I wish I could use a file instead

Comment: this doesn't seem possible... https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/41711. I'll try your suggestion and let you know how it works out, thanks again

Comment: this works well, though, I'll be forever bothered that I can't use a file :(